# Why ubuntu gparted show unallocated spaces but windows disk management dont

Tags: 18.04, disk-management

Why ubuntu gparted show unallocated spaces but windows disk management dont.

See the differance:

[image: gparted]
[image: disk management]

Comment: I suspect if windows showed it, people would be asking questions "*why?*" & "*I don't want to waste the space, how can I use it?*" - so microsoft coders saved themselves that hassle and just hid it.   Then again maybe it was just hiding it from their boss  (*re-code it so that 2mb of space isn't wasted*)